# PHP mySql - change statement to NOT delete certain values?

Tags: php, mysql

```
DELETE FROM banned_users WHERE datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE)
```

I'm currently using the above to only delete accounts where the ban has lifted, however can i change the statement to NOT delete items where 'ban_length' != "INF"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have other requirements, then this should do the trick:

```
DELETE FROM banned_users WHERE ban_length != 'INF' && datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE)
```

Comment: I'd need it to DELETE WHERE X = X 'AND NOT DELETE WHERE X = Y' does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, now I understand your issue. The updated answer should contain both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM banned_users WHERE datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE) && ban_length != 'INF'
```

Answer (score 0):

*Not* delete items where `ban_length != 'INF'`? So delete items only when `ban_length = 'INF'`?

```
DELETE FROM banned_users
WHERE datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE)
AND ban_length = 'INF';
```

Comment: seem to be getting Unknown column '$ban' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

After 5.1.24, mysql provide NULL for INF，INF and NaN. If you are using mysql greater than 5.1.24, you can try this:

```
DELETE FROM banned_users WHERE datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE) AND ban_length=NULL
```

or， you can try that：

```
DELETE FROM banned_users WHERE datetime < (NOW() - INTERVAL $ban MINUTE) AND ban_length=INF
```